# Can Visual Studio's debugger have its "array safety" disabled?

Tags: arrays, debugging, release-mode

What I'm referring to is the fact that in Debug mode you can sometimes get away with an array overflow, but then in Release mode it crashes and you have no idea which of the arrays is giving the problem (my code is really big). Can I disable the extra padding, so the crash would also occur in debug mode, so I can check which function causes it on the call stack?

Answer (score 1):

Build `Release` as usual but [enable debug symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx), this way you can trace the crash in `Release` binaries.

**[It is recommeneded to ALWAYS enable symbols for `Release` builds](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx)**; generating and saving the `.pdb` files allows you to then easily open up a dump or minidump from the field and find out what the problem was without necessarily having to reproduce it in-house.  You don't have to include them in your installer or give them to customers, just put them aside alongside your binaries somewhere you can easily retrieve them from.